# It's a book of my mother's VS It's my mother's book

Tags: possessives

Am I right about this:

**It's a book of my mother's** - it proves she has several books and this one

**It's my mother's book** - it doesn't prove the other books' existence. It proves only this one's one, doesn't it?

Comment: Neither indicates that she owns any other books.

Comment: Perfect!
But is any of them formal, informal or both variants are the equal to each other?

Comment: To me (not an objective answer), the second sentence sounds more direct and is slightly simpler to parse.